# Разобрать массив и взять значения

Tags: php, массивы, битрикс

Помогите справиться с массивом

имеется такой массив битрикса24 -

```
{
    "result": [{
            "ID": "150",
            "EMAIL": [{
                    "ID": "172",
                    "VALUE_TYPE": "WORK",
                    "VALUE": "666@666.666",
                    "TYPE_ID": "EMAIL"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "total": 1,
    "time": {
        "start": 1515742416.5858,
        "finish": 1515742416.6568,
        "duration": 0.070952892303467,
        "date_start": "2018-01-12T10:33:36+03:00",
        "date_finish": "2018-01-12T10:33:36+03:00"
    }
}
```

не получается забрать `"ID":"172"` и `"VALUE":"666@666.666"`

я пишу - `echo $result['result'][0]['ID']` - выводит `150` (`"ID":"150"`) все правильно.
А когда пишу так `echo $result['result'][0]['ID']['EMAIL'][0]['ID']`
вместо`"ID":"172"` - у меня выводит `1`

помогите разобраться с массивом, господа. Может есть более легкий способ вывода элементов массива?

Comment: потому что это не массив, а  json строка, которую надо вначале перевести в массив `$result = json_decode($str, true)`

Comment: Приложите к вопросу вывод `print_r($result);`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский - возможно Битрикс уже как-то по своему эту строку обрабатывает.

Comment: @AlexeyShatrov судя по `1` - вряд ли. Можно посоветовать ТС воспользоваться отладкой и посмотреть чего он творит))
 [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/Как-и-какими-средствами-находить-ошибки-в-php-коде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701142/191482)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = '{"result":[{"ID":"150","EMAIL":[{"ID":"172","VALUE_TYPE":"WORK","VALUE":"666@666.666","TYPE_ID":"EMAIL"}]}],"total":1,"time":{"start":1515742416.5858,"finish":1515742416.6568,"duration":0.070952892303467,"date_start":"2018-01-12T10:33:36+03:00","date_finish":"2018-01-12T10:33:36+03:00"}}';


$data = json_decode($str, true);
$id = $data['result'][0]['ID'];
$email = $data['result'][0]['EMAIL'][0]['VALUE'];

var_dump($id, $email);
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 1):

зачем вы пишите

```
$result['result'][0]['ID']['EMAIL'][0]['ID']
```

если надо

```
$result['result'][0]['EMAIL'][0]['VALUE']
```

?

Comment: Спасибо за найденный косяк !